# Too many redirects nginx + magento

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

My server environment is ubuntu + nginx + mysql, And there is a problem since 2 months like after browsing Magento long time we are getting "**www.example.com redirected you too many times**" in browser. It is happening quite frequently in a day (2-3 times in a day). After clearing the browser cache and cookies then it works like normal. 
We are using Magento 1.9.3 version.
We recently installed new SSL.

Hope above information will help, Could anybody please help me how to fix it?

Below is nginx config file

```
 server {
    listen    8080;
    server_name www.example.com.au example.com.au;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    root        /var/www/vhosts/www.example.com.au;

 index index.html index.php;
    port_in_redirect off;   
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.au-access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.au-error_log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
        proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
     proxy_read_timeout 180s;

    }
    location /newmod/{
try_files $uri $uri/newmod/ @handler1;
expires 0d;
    }           

    location /newmod/app/                       { deny all; }
    location /newmod/includes/                  { deny all; }
    location /newmod/lib/                       { deny all; }
    location /newmod/media/downloadable/        { deny all; }
    location /newmod/pkginfo/                   { deny all; }
    location /newmod/report/config.xml          { deny all; }
    location /newmod/var/                       { deny all; }
    location /xmlrpc.php                  { deny all; }
    location /newmod/downloader/                {deny all;}
    location /newmod/dev/                       {deny all; }
    location /newmod/var/export/ {
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
        autoindex               on;
    }
    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
        rewrite /sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite /([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
    }
location @handler1{
rewrite /newmod /newmod/index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 2400s;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

    location /lib/minify/ {
        allow all;
    }
    gzip on;
    #gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/xml text/html text/css text/js application/x-javascript;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to many redirection is happen due to 2 reason.

1. your magento Web URL are wrong.
2. yournginx configuration wrong.
   i assume here is that you are using two port 80 and 443.
   now you have to changes 2 things
3. magento web urls.(if need)
4. nginx configurations.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/html/www.example.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name www.example.com;
  resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 10s;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  #ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
  #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  .......
}
```

put you other code in place of .....
hope you get your answer